# Trying to make Visual Studio Code Extension, 3 questions

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I am trying to make a visual studio code extension that basically grabs the current lines value and parses it and turns px to rem, (I have made these variables as later I wish to modify the base and units)

All I can see on the Microsoft API site is how to get the highlighted value, So I went with this first as I figured I wanted to just get the function working first.

Then with my code I am unsure on how to return it as a final value if the line is more than 1 value eg,

margin: 22px 32px 0 32px;

Below is the code.

```
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.pxToEm', () => {
        var base, editor, initBase, original, selection, text, unit, values, totalBase, position;
        editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        selection = editor.selection;
        text = editor.document.getText(selection);
        base = <any>16;
        unit = 'rem';
        values = text.match(/([0-9]+)px/gi);
        var returnValue = function(text) {
            if (values !== null) {
                values.forEach(function(val, key) {
                    text = text.replace(val, parseInt(val) / base + unit);
                    if (key > values.length - 1) {
                        totalBase = '/' + base.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gi, '');
                        text = text.replace(totalBase, ' ').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gi, '');
                        text = text + '\n';
                    }
                });
            }
            return text;
        };
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(returnValue(text));
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my code, It works correctly now however I just wish to use it by the cursors current line.. i have no idea. any help would be appreciated (so get content from the current line instead of selection and also replace it on return

Answer (score 2):

You could use the selection object, like this:

```
editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
selection = editor.selection;
if(selection.isEmpty)
{
    // the Position object gives you the line and character where the cursor is
      const position = editor.selection.active;
      var newPosition = position.with(position.line, 0);
      var newSelection = new vscode.Selection(newPosition, newPosition);
      editor.selection = newSelection;
}
text = editor.document.getText(selection);
```